# Why do components and entities become hidden inconsistently?

Tags: sketchup

I created a wall and duplicated it.  I cut the wall, clicked on a different tag so it was selected, and then edited the tag so the pencil icon was visible.  Pasting, or pasting into always causes that geometry to appear with the original tag.

Exporting it to a stand-alone file and re-importing it produces the same results.

Why can't I get this geometry on the tag I want? Is there a way to do what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sketchup, a group or component's individual entities can exist on different tags.  For example, if I created a tag called "Foundation", and created a component called "Joist", the geometry for "Joist" would exist within the "Foundation" tag. Thus, if moved the joists to a new layer called "First Floor", hiding "Foundation" would also hide all the joists.

To solve this problem, I've created component layers that contain the geometry for my components that are separate from my other groupings which I want to hide and show.